# Swift: Detect when first letter(s) of a string isn't equal to particular character?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, for-loop, swift3

I have a simple string. I want to be able to detect when any word within that particular string does not have a **#** at the start of it and if so, execute some code. I have give it a go but my solution seems to be a little glitchy and not very reliable. Sometimes it executes the correct line and sometimes it doesn't. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Thank you guys.

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == String {
    var initials: [String] {
        return map{String($0.characters.prefix(1))}
    }
}

let string: String = "Hello this is a #test"
let stringArray = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
print(stringArray.count)
let array = Array(stringArray)

    let firstLetter = array.initials
    for letter in firstLetter {
        if letter != "#" {
            print("tell user to add hashtag")
        } else {
            print("successful")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach using String's `hasPrefix()` method:

```
let string = "Hello this is a #test"

for word in string.components(separatedBy: " ") {
    if !word.hasPrefix("#") {
        print("tell user to add hashtag")
    } else {
        print("successful")
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome approach. Thank you, Sir.